# Few basic doubts regarding caches

Tags: algorithm, caching

Please bear with me , these questions may be very basic . I am just trying to understand the fundamentals.

1. Are the cache eviction algorithms such as LRU are implemented by the OS ?? if so , how can we find out the current algorithm being used and is it possible for the programer to change it ?
2. Since cache is along with processor , the read and write policies are hardcoded or the operating system decides it ?
3. Are there separate caches for data and instructions ? or do they share the same cache ?
4. What are the algorithms currently employed in operating systems to solve cache coherency problem ?

Thanks for your patience in answering my questions.

- Sethu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just one answer? Well

1.) No hardware implemented. They should be documented by the vendor, if not then [microbenchmarking](http://www.eecg.toronto.edu/~myrto/gpuarch-ispass2010.pdf) is an option.

2.) Hardware

3.) As pointed out above L1 cache has separate caches for data and instruction. There is also TLB for virtual memory.

4.) I attended a course last semester which covers these topics. The slides are available online: http://www.systems.ethz.ch/education/past-courses/hs09/mmdbms

Answer (score 1):

In general, the cache policy is dictated by hardware.  There are typically separate data and instruction caches, as well as a *translation lookaside buffer* (TLB) cache.  The OS has no direct control of cache, but it may make decisions in virtual-memory mappings to optimise cache usage.

Comment: Is it possible to find out which cache policy is used by coherent processors ? Do they expose it in some manual ??

Comment: If hardware triggers a miss , who will fetch the memory data ? OS ? does the hardware takes care of flushing/eviction ? sorry I am asking alot of questions ,i am just trying to understand the concepts

Comment: TLB = "translation lookaside buffer" (not "transaction")